# to crash a swimmer, surfer, etc., heavily downwards

Tags: word-meaning

> **dump**
>
> 10. (transitive, Australia) Of **a surf wave**, to crash **a swimmer, surfer, etc.**, heavily ***downwards***.

Source: dump - Wiktionary

---

I'm not sure if "***downwards***" means (the direction that "**a surf wave**" crashes "**a swimmer, surfer, etc.**).

Comment: What else could it mean?

Comment: Personally, I would change that Wikipedia entry to: push a swimmer or surfer deeper into the water or towards the bottom. "crash a surfer" is not great. I am a surfer and ocean swimmer. It's like water in a bucket. Imagine you are a tiny human being in a bucket of water and someone **dumps** it on the ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a wave dumps a surfer, it forcefully pushes them under the water. In this case *downwards* is the direction of gravity: **towards the bottom of the water**. Here's a quote from a recent [Guardian article](https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2020/jan/04/getting-dumped-the-humiliating-nostalgia-of-a-beachside-wipeout):

> Being **dumped** by a wave was harder to describe. Years before the term had romantic implications, getting **dumped** – usually in front of your friends – was still a singularly humiliating experience. A great equaliser. No matter how cool you were, you could still go arse over feet with the whole beach watching.

Wiktionary has

> downwards (adv.): Towards a lower place; towards what is below.
>
> > *Gravity pulls everything downwards.*

Comment: The bottom of the water? Towards the ocean floor....